Module '"react-native-reanimated-carousel"' has no exported member 'TAnimationStyle'
I encountered the error when looking at these examples: react-native-reanimated-carousel example. I do not know how to solve the error and did not find a solution on this platform or anywhere online for that matter.
I am new to animations so any help is greatly appreciated.

you can install latest npm package of react-native-reanimated
npm i react-native-reanimated-carousel@4.0.0-canary.15

Hi, @ansardeen. Thanks for the answer. It would be helpful if you could explain why you believe that will help. Did previous versions of the library not include that exported member? Is there some other reason OP needs the new version? Or are you just saying he needs to reinstall and that will somehow fix things? Good answers include not just an action to take, but the reasons why it will work, to help readers learn from the experience and have confidence that this is a good solution. Cheers!
